# OpenCV cuda enabled build doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda

I am working opencv and i built opencv with cuda enabled. I am doing this using remote desktop connection since my pc doesn't have nvidia. I am doing it on visual studio 2010 64 bit. But after it has finished, the function `gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` still returns zero. I don't understand it.

Comment: I am not sure about how this works with cuda but when you do a remote desktop you get a virtual gpu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882124/how-to-run-a-cuda-code-using-remote-desktop

Comment: You can also try [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It worked for me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use a GPU in a PC that you have connected to via remote desktop connection.  Either work on that PC locally, or else use another method such as VNC to connect to the PC.

**EDIT:** Newer NVIDIA drivers (r352, so 353.xx or newer) have worked around this RDP limitation, and a supported CUDA WDDM GPU should now be visible in a RDP session with these drivers.